# Pyfacebook from buildout

Tags: python, facebook, github, buildout, pypi

What is the best way to install the latest version of pyfacebook with buildout? The package is hosted on github and is not on pypi. This system doesn't have git installed, so a git-based recipe isn't unfortunately not an option. The github URL is http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook. TIA!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add any python package hosted on git-hub by adding a find-links url pointing to the project tarball URL plus a `#egg=packagename` postfix. For pyfacebook that is:

```
http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/tarball/master#egg=pyfacebook
```

So a simple buildout would be:

```
[buildout]
parts = whatever
find-links =
    http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/tarball/master#egg=pyfacebook
eggs = pyfacebook
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked great. I moved this to the setup.py in order to not be locked into buildout in the future:

    dependency_links=['http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/tarball/master#egg=pyfacebook'],
    install_requires = ['pyfacebook'],